# 'process' var is undefined in Vue / Typescript component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, environment-variables

I am having a problem getting `.env` variables working in my Vue app. After `npm install process` this was the only syntax that didn't throw an error when trying to import.

```
import * as process from 'process';
```

Before this I also had the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.
```

I ran this install and added "node" to `types` in my `tsconfig` file.

I have a member variable defined like so,

```
const testVar = process.env.TEST_VAR
```

and have tried both `TEST_VAR=just test` and `TEST_VAR="just test"` inside my .env file.

The .env file itself is placed in the root folder of the project, ie. outside the `src` folder, but I have tried placing it inside the `src` folder also.

Despite all that, the var is coming back undefined.

```
mounted(){
 console.log('ENV TEST -> ', this.testVar)
 alert(`ENV2 : ${this.testVar}`)
 ...
}
```

I'd be very grateful for any help solving this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you installed the right package? Reading the Readme on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process) you can read `This module mostly exists to provide the nextTick functionality and little more`. Maybe everything you needed was `declare const process`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna perhaps the package is not correct. I will need to check. I have also installed `dotenv` but can't figure out how to use it in my component using Typescript.

Comment: It's a mistake to use and import process package. `process` is exposed by a bundler, which is unknown in your case. For Webpack/Vue CLI `webpack-env` is used to provide respective TS types, can be used in `types` tsconfig section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle. [Vue docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

And then it will be accessible in the components

```
mounted() {
 console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_TEST_VAR)
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks!